# Array sizes are inconsistent warning won't go away

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

edit added :

I have this multidimensional array which I sort:

```
foreach ($IJ as $key => $row) {
        $schap[$key]  = $row['loc'];
        $schap[$key]  = $row['schap'];
        $number[$key] = $row['number'];
        $rest[$key] = $row['rest'];

        }


array_multisort($number, SORT_ASC, $IJ);
```

This is the var_dump from the field thats get sorted:

```
[0]=> string(2) "16" [1]=> string(2) "10" [2]=> string(2) "08" [3]=> string(2) "07" [4]=> string(2) "05" [5]=> string(2) "05" [6]=> string(2) "04" [7]=> string(2) "04" [8]=> string(2) "03" [9]=> string(2) "03" [10]=> string(2) "03"
```

They are all the same type and length but I still get the warning that they are inconsistent. I tried everything from converting all the values to ints. I have the same problem when I try to sort 2 multidimensional arrays that are the same. Maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: Do `$number` and `$EF` contain the same number of elements? The error message is telling you that they don't

Comment: Please check the link and see example 2:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: $number is the name of the dimension to sort and $EF is name of the array. so $number is an element of $EF

Comment: `var_dump(count($number), count($IJ))` - what does that give you?

Comment: According to @anantkumarsingh's link and example 3, it looks correct. The only clue is that `$number` is not empty before your loop... otherwise they must have same keys, so same count... can you add `$number = array()` before your loop ?

Comment: var_dump: int(16) int(6)  hmmmmm, there's the problem I think

Comment: @random $number is never empty because it's a substring of another string that gets checked before substringin.

Comment: $number is a string ?? I must miss something... and how can you have a int(16) and int(6) in your var dump... in the question, your array has 10 fields...

Comment: @random I changed it from string to int, the var_dump was old & i didn't dump all the output. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If your comment

> $number is the name of the dimension to sort and $EF is name of the array. so $number is an element of $EF

is valid, then this is what you should do:

```
array_multisort($EF[$number], SORT_ASC);
```

Actually, you don't need `array_multisort` to achieve this. One of the other [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) would be enough.

Comment: array_push($IJ, array('loc' => $loc_sub, 'schap' => $schap_sub, 'number' => $number_sub, 'rest' => $rest_sub)); So I think it's valid. All dimensions are never empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was sure there was nothing wrong with my code so I did some digging trough my code and I found out that a few lines before the array_mulisort my array($IJ) got more entries in in it. thats why it had 16 entries instead of 6.

Thanx everybody for the help and the suggestions.